# Duplicated collection won't stop moving with the original collection

Tags: modeling

I'm really sorry if the answer to my problem is obvious, but I just can't seem to find a solution on my own.

I have duplicated a collection of meshes and I want to be able to move them individually into their respective positions. I select all of the meshes within one collection and select their vertices:

[image]

I then attempt to move one of the collections as a whole, assuming it would work because I've already selected the relevant vertices. When I do, both the original collection that I duplicated from and the duplicate itself move together:

[image]

Is there any way to stop the two collections moving together? I just find it odd, since 'Piston 2' itself is a duplicate, but doesn't move with *its* original.

Huge thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like you *linked duplicate*, so the mesh data is the same for the objects in both collections. Notice in the outliner the green icons are highlighted when you select the objects of the other collection in edit mode. You can make them single users. Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & data.

Comment: @Gorgious That worked perfectly. I was banging my head against a wall trying to find a fix, thank you ever so much. :)